# Buildozer failed to execute the last command to convert kivy to apk

Tags: python, android, linux, bash, kivy

I am trying to convert test python kivy file to apk. I wanted to avoid long methods such downloading virtualbox and running linux on the virtual machine, so I decided to use bash console on pythoneverywhere.com . I followed carefully instructions from https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html but the last command `buildozer android debug deploy run` does not work and the output is the following:

```
11:13 ~/buildozer (master)$ buildozer android debug deploy run
# Check configuration tokens
# WARNING: Config token app android.sdk is deprecated and ignored, but you set value 24
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /home/denezioden69420/.buildozer
# Create directory /home/denezioden69420/.buildozer/cache
# Create directory /home/denezioden69420/.buildozer/android/platform/android/platform
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.4 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/denezioden69420/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/denezioden69420/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 52abfe9 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2118 from AndreMiras/feature/bump_openssl_master
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'
pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will d
rop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
# Android ANT is missing, downloading
# Downloading http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz
# Run 'tar xzf apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz'
# Cwd /home/denezioden69420/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
# Command failed: tar xzf apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     http_proxy = 'http://proxy.server:3128'
#     LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf-8'
#     PYTHONANYWHERE_DOMAIN = 'pythonanywhere.com'
#     USER = 'denezioden69420'
#     PATH = '/home/denezioden69420/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/denezioden69420/.local/bin:/home/denezioden69420/.local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin'
#     HOME = '/home/denezioden69420'
#     VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT = '/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     https_proxy = 'http://proxy.server:3128'
#     PYTHONANYWHERE_SITE = 'www.pythonanywhere.com'
#     SUDO_USER = 'root'
#     JAVA_HOME = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64'
#     USERNAME = 'denezioden69420'
#     WORKON_HOME = '/home/denezioden69420/.virtualenvs'
#     SUDO_COMMAND = '/bin/bash -l -c cd  .;cd . ; cd /home/denezioden69420; exec bash '
#     SUDO_UID = '0'
#     VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD = '1'
#     PYENCHANT_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/lib/libenchant.so.1'
#     _ = '/home/denezioden69420/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME = '.project'
#     SUDO_GID = '0'
#     VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR = '/home/denezioden69420/.virtualenvs'
#     PYTHONSTARTUP = '/home/denezioden69420/.pythonstartup.py'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/denezioden69420'
#     HISTCONTROL = 'ignoreboth'
#     no_proxy = 'localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com,/var/run/docker.sock'
#     PWD = '/home/denezioden69420/buildozer'
#     LOGNAME = 'denezioden69420'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

It says that it cannot unzip this file – android-ndk-r19b-linux-x86_64.zip however if I open the file it seems that it is not zip file but html:

```
<html><head>
<meta type="copyright" content="Copyright (C) 1996-2015 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
<style type="text/css"><!-- 
 /*
 * Copyright (C) 1996-2015 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors
 *
 * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and includes
 * contributions from numerous individuals and organizations.
 * Please see the COPYING and CONTRIBUTORS files for details.
 */

/*
 Stylesheet for Squid Error pages
 Adapted from design by Free CSS Templates
 http://www.freecsstemplates.org
 Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License
*/

/* Page basics */
* {
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

html body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #efefef;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #1e1e1e;
}

/* Page displayed title area */
#titles {
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    background: url('/squid-internal-static/icons/SN.png') no-repeat left;
}

/* initial title */
#titles h1 {
    color: #000000;
}
#titles h2 {
    color: #000000;
}

/* special event: FTP success page titles */
#titles ftpsuccess {
    background-color:#00ff00;
    width:100%;
}

/* Page displayed body content area */
#content {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

/* General text */
p {
}

/* error brief description */
#error p {
}

/* some data which may have caused the problem */
#data {
}

/* the error message received from the system or other software */
#sysmsg {
}

pre {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

/* special event: FTP / Gopher directory listing */
#dirmsg {
    font-family: courier;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#dirlisting {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
#dirlisting tr.entry td.icon,td.filename,td.size,td.date {
    border-bottom: groove;
}
#dirlisting td.size {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* horizontal lines */
hr {
    margin: 0;
}

/* page displayed footer area */
#footer {
    font-size: 9px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}


body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
 --></style>
</head><body id="ERR_UNSUP_REQ">
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19b-linux-x86_64.zip">https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19b-linux-x86_64.zip</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Unsupported Request Method and Protocol</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p>Squid does not support all request methods for all access protocols. For example, you can not POST a Gopher request.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo%20-%20ERR_UNSUP_REQ&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20blue-liveproxy1%0D%0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_UNSUP_REQ%0D%0AErr%3A%20%5Bnone%5D%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Sat,%2004%20Apr%202020%2009%3A50%3A23%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%3A%2010.0.0.97%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0AGET%20%2Fandroid%2Frepository%2Fandroid-ndk-r19b-linux-x86_64.zip%20HTTP%2F1.0%0AUser-Agent%3A%20Mozilla%2F5.0%20(X11%3B%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F28.0.1500.71%20Safari%2F537.36%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">webmaster</a>.</p>
<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Sat, 04 Apr 2020 09:50:23 GMT by blue-liveproxy1 (squid/3.5.12)</p>
<!-- ERR_UNSUP_REQ -->
</div>
</body></html>
```

The file at `/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4` is:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
     Access Denied
  </HEAD>
<BODY>

<h1>Access Denied</h1>

<p>
Access to arbitrary websites is not available from free accounts;
you can only access sites that are on our
<a href="http://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist">whitelist</a>.
If you want to suggest something to add to our whitelist
drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com.  It will have
to have an official public API.
</p>


<p>
Alternatively, you can sign up for a paid account at
<a href="http://www.pythonanywhere.com/account/">http://www.pythonanywhere.com/account/</a>
</p>
<p>
If you have already got a paid account and you're still getting this messge,
you may need to reload your web app (from the "Web" tab) or restart
your consoles.  If that doesn't help, drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com.
</p>

</BODY>
```

Comment: take a look at the last file you posted. if you are using pythonanywhere and you are trying to accessing an external site you need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Try first just converting it to apk

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug arising from the download url no longer being available. It should be fixed in p4a master, which buildozer is supposed to be pulling here unless you changed it.

To resolve for now, try changing the NDK version entry in buildozer.spec to `19c`.

Comment: Didn't work out, unfortunately. Output is the same.

Comment: What exactly did you change?

Comment: In buildozer.spec I changed
# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b
to 
# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19c

Comment: You need to uncomment the line, remove the # at the start.

Comment: I've changed and still no. Maybe I should've changed something else. Could you please have a quick look at my spec file? https://pastebin.com/yaPWpn8z

Comment: Please post the full output log from when you run buildozer. Also, before doing that try deleting the `~/.buildozer` directory just in case there's some cached state.

Comment: I edited my question, now there is full output log after I deleted ```.buildozer``` and ran command ```buildozer android debug deploy run```.

Comment: You're having a different issue now, `# Command failed: tar xzf apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz`. The log suggests it isn't in gzip format. I checked the url and this time it does exist as expected. Are you able to locate the downloaded file and work out what it actually is?

Comment: Yes, it looks like html. I've edit question and added contents of this file.

Comment: Read the file you just pasted, it quite effectively explains what the problem is.

Comment: Yeap, It indeed explains.